# Icon in option - Font-awsome

Tags: html, font-awesome

I am trying to embed font awesome icons in select option.
I tried with `<i>` as well as `&#xf000;` but both are not working.
If any body has it's solution please guide on the same

Comment: post your not working code

Comment: Browser will **always use** system (!) **default font** for option list items so you can't put a <i> there. If you really need it you have to use a custom drawn option control.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to style the option of a html "select"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select)

Comment: It's not about styling folks..i want to disply all icons from font-awesome under a drop down

Comment: This is the code which is not displaying font icons' <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="<?php echo $name; ?>">
      
      <option <?php if($value=='adjust') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> <?php if($name=='adjust') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="adjust"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></option>
      <option  <?php if($value=='asterisk') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="asterisk"><i>&#xf001;</i></option></select>'

Comment: **We** understand. The problem is **you can't put <i> inside <select> items because browsers will always render them as plain text**, using system default font (or body font, maybe). No CSS applied. No markup (tags will be simply stripped out). Plain pure text.

Comment: @user42701 - if Adriano's comment wasn't enough for you, checkout the link that Quentin posted.

Comment: @Adriano Correct this is my exact problem

Comment: @user42701 answer is still...you can't! You have to use a **custom** dropdown (made, for example, using <ul> and styled to appear and behave like a combobox). There are many examples of that (check jQuery plugins).